# Uploading an updated version of the document requires me to re-enter metadata

Tags: document-library, document, metadata

For my document library, I've added some additional metadata columns that needed to be specified.

[image: Add new document]

The only way I know how to upload a new document to overwrite/update another document is to choose *New Document*, choose the file, and specify *overwrite existing files*.

[image: Overwrite file]

But doing it this way makes me re-enter all the metadata again, which is unacceptable for the solution we're developing.

[image: Re-enter data]

How can I upload a new file to overwrite an existing file, leaving the metadata in place for that file?

*SharePoint 2013 On-premise.*